# When is it appropriate to use "did + verb" in a who-question?

Tags: questions, simple-past, do

I know that one can say "I did take the money" in order to stress the action. For instance, "You didn't take the money, did you?" - "I did take the money! I told you already so many times."

But when is it allowed in who-questions, e.g. "Who did take the money?"

Comment: Makes perfect sense. But are there any other situations where "Who did take the money?" is justified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bruce: The money was stolen, you tell me, John. Well, I don't think Molly took it.

John: But then, who **did take** it then?

COMPARE:
John: But then, who took it?

Summary: In John's question **who did take it** is used instead of **who took it**. The use of *did take* is used to emphasize the fact it was taken.

The implicit suggestion is that previously in a conversation someone has said that some person did not take it. It is a way of being more emphatic.

*Do* can also be used for emphasis:
If you **don't do laundry for us** here, who **does do** it?

- [Auxiliary for emphasis](http://www.grammaring.com/the-auxiliary-did-for-emphasis)

Answer (score 0):

But when is it allowed in who-questions, e.g. "Who did take the money?"

Implicit in the example are unspoken words (a restrictive clause), to the effect: **if** not you **then** who. So you see, that in such context the addition of did makes the question more restrictive (in the practical as well as grammatical) sense (look up *restrictive clause*).